# Return file URL from modal Dialog containing upload form

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, file-upload, sharepoint-clientobject

How do you return the URL of a file after it has been uploaded to a document library in SharePoint, using the default upload page? Returning the text from the "inputFile" textbox from the upload.aspx page would also work, but I can't figure out how to do that because it's loaded inside a modal dialog.

```
function uploadPicture(){
var currentUserDispName ='myname';
var options = {
    url: '/test/_layouts/15/Upload.aspx?List=6c7bc1b3%2D1b7f%2D466b%2Da0f5%2Dac15dc334ff7& RootFolder=/test/mydocs/' +      currentUserDispName + "&IsDlg=1",
    width: 450,
    height: 230,
    title: 'Upload a Picture',
    dialogReturnValueCallback: function(result, returnValue) {

    if (result == SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
          //get File URL
    } 
    else {                     
    //else
   }
    }; SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);}
```

Comment: In your dialogReturnValueCallback you have returnValue parameter. What value does it has?

Comment: It doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I ended up doing to get the file name was using SPquery.  I just made a query to retrieve all items and ordered them using last modified field, and setting the rowlimit to 1.  Once I did that, I can find the serverRelative URL of the file.

Answer (score 2):

you could use `returnValue.newFileUrl` in the callback function

```
function OpenModalDialogOrganoAdministracion() {
  var options = {
             url: 'http://servidor/libreria',
             title: 'Añadir Documento',
             allowMaximize: false,
             showClose: false,
             width: 800,
             height: 600,
             dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult,returnValue){
                        if(dialogResult==SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) {
                          alert(returnValue.newFileUrl); 
                        }
             }
            };
SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
}
```

Comment: Either post it as a comment, or describe your answer.

Comment: Just set *Upload.aspx* path in `url` and it works. (Tested within SP2016.)

Answer (score 0):

It's not really what you're asking, but I use another way to upload/create a file into a Sharepoint document library: [SharepointPlus - createFile()](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/symbols/%24SP%28%29.html#.createFile)

That way it's the user that defines the name of the file. So you already know the name :-) You may need to first check the name doesn't exist already in the library before uploading it.

I hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks that looks like a useful extension.